# Simple jQuery list toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a question it slides open fine, but how can make it so if I click on it again it hides it if visible?

Thanks!
Jon

```js
$('.faqDisplay dt').click(function() {
  var item = $($(this).parent()).children('dd');
  if (item.css('display', 'none')) {
    item.slideDown();
  } else {
    item.slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
.faqDisplay dd {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqDisplay">

  <dl>
    <dt>Question One</dt>
    <dd>
      <p>Answer One</p>
    </dd>
  </dl>

  <dl>
    <dt>Question Two</dt>
    <dd>
      <p>Answer Two</p>
    </dd>
  </dl>

</div>
```

Comment: `.hide()` https://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `slideToggle()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/868/)

```js
$('dt').click(function() {
  $(this).next('dd').slideToggle();
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this works in your example but when I add to my site and click on a question, the content slides down and slidles back up again, it won't stay down. Is there something that can be added to stop this?

Comment: Try adding  `id` like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/869/ it could be some other code that creates that problem. Also try this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/870/

Answer (score 0):

try changing this `if(item.css('display','none')) {`
to this `if(!item.is(':visible')) {`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.faqDisplay dt').click(function(){
  var item = $($(this).parent()).children('dd');
  if(!item.is(':visible')) {
  item.slideToggle();
  }
  else {
    item.slideToggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.faqDisplay dd {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqDisplay">
  
  <dl>
    <dt>Question One</dt>
    <dd>
      <p>Answer One</p>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  
  <dl>
    <dt>Question Two</dt>
    <dd>
      <p>Answer Two</p>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: It seems that at least since jQuery 1.7, this version of .toggle is deprecated, probably for exactly that reason, namely that two versions exist. Using .toggle to change the visibility of elements is just a more common usage. The method was removed in jQuery 1.9.

```
function a(el){
   el.slideDown();; 
}
function b(el){
  el.slideUp();
}

$('.faqDisplay dt').click(function() {
  var el = this;
  return (el.t = !el.t) ? a(el) : b(el);
});
```